# Picasso image load incredibly laggy in android listview?

Tags: android, image, listview, picasso

In my application, I am using the last.fm api, picasso, and "artist" & "album" strings to fetch album art images for a listview feed. When I scroll through the feed, it is super laggy and I'm not sure why. If there is new data, a button appears on the screen to update, and it scrolls to the top of the listview. When I use picasso to fetch images, the auto scroll is incredibly laggy. If I am using a stored png or something, it works fine.

Here is my getView() method in custom adapter class--this particular layout is "playcut" in the switch case:

```
case PLAYCUT_LAYOUT: //Playcut
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);

            convertView.findViewById(R.id.play).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.cell_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image);

            holder.cell_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_album_art);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/");
            stringBuilder.append("?method=album.getinfo");
            stringBuilder.append("&api_key=");
            stringBuilder.append("2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15");
            String albumURL;

            try{
                stringBuilder.append("&artist=" + URLEncoder.encode(oslist.get(position).get("artistName"), "UTF-8"));
                stringBuilder.append("&album=" + URLEncoder.encode(oslist.get(position).get("releaseTitle"), "UTF-8"));
                albumURL = new RetrieveAlbumArtUrlTask().execute(stringBuilder.toString()).get();
                Picasso.with(context).load(albumURL).error(R.drawable.no_album_art).into(holder.cell_image);

            }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){

            } catch(InterruptedException e){

            } catch(ExecutionException e){

            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                Log.v("TEST","SUP");
                holder.cell_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_album_art);
            }

            holder.song = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song);
            holder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);

            holder.song.setText(oslist.get(position).get("songTitle"));
            holder.artist.setText(oslist.get(position).get("artistName"));


            final RelativeLayout playcutLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playcut);

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        updateView(position);

                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            break;
        case NULL_LAYOUT:
```

And here is a relevant AsyncTask method in that same class:

```
public class RetrieveAlbumArtUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String albumArtUrl = null;
        try {

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(urls[0]); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                if(e.getAttribute("size").contentEquals("extralarge")){
                    albumArtUrl = parser.getElementValue(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return albumArtUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the retrieve `RetrieveAlbumArtUrlTask` and the String concatenation that occurs there (however fast it might be).

Each time your view is created (when scrolled) :

1. The `getView()` method will go through the `switch` statement
2. View will be drawn as requested by each `case`
3. On the `PlayCut` `case`

   This stringBuilder operation can be replaced

   **Old**

   ```
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/");
       stringBuilder.append("?method=album.getinfo");
       stringBuilder.append("&api_key=");
       stringBuilder.append("2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15");

       String albumURL;

       try{
           stringBuilder.append("&artist=" + URLEncoder.encode(oslist.get(position).get("artistName"), "UTF-8"));
           stringBuilder.append("&album=" + URLEncoder.encode(oslist.get(position).get("releaseTitle"), "UTF-8"));
           albumURL = new RetrieveAlbumArtUrlTask().execute(stringBuilder.toString()).get();
           Picasso.with(context).load(albumURL).error(R.drawable.no_album_art).into(holder.cell_image);

       }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){

       } catch(InterruptedException e){

       } catch(ExecutionException e){

       } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
           Log.v("TEST","SUP");
           holder.cell_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_album_art);
       }
   ```

   **New**

   ```
       //make a constant field with value 
       //"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15&artist=%s&album=%s"
       //maybe like 

       private static final String APIURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15&artist=%s&album=%s";

       //then use 

       String artistName =  URLEncoder.encode(oslist.get(position).get("artistName"), "UTF-8");
       String albumName = URLEncoder.encode(oslist.get(position).get("albumName"), "UTF-8");
       String albumURL = new RetrieveAlbumArtUrlTask().execute(String.format(APIURL, artistName, albumName)).get();

       //then use picasso as usual
   ```

I think String operations during `getView()` is costly, therefore I'd like to keep it minimum.

Also, can you try doing the picasso loading without `RetrieveAlbumArtUrlTask` ? If it is indeed faster, then the Background task is the culprit